# How to replace string in Hive

Tags: sql, regex, hive, hiveql

I have data like below in my hive tables:

```
FirstName

Mr Tim Cannon
Guest
Miss Kerri Smith
Missra
```

I'm trying to use

```
INITCAP(REGEXP_REPLACE('Miss Missra','(Mr.)|^Mr$|^Ms.$|^Ms$|^Mrs.$|^Mrs$|^Dr.$|^Dr$|^Miss$',' '))
```

but still it is same.

When tried using

```
INITCAP(REGEXP_REPLACE('Miss Missra','(\\+)|(Mr.)|^Mr$|^Ms.$|^Ms$|^Mrs.$|^Mrs$|^Dr.$|^Dr$|Miss',' '))
```

then it is replacing 'Missra' as 'Ra'

Output should be:

```
FirstName

Tim Cannon
Guest
Kerri Smith
Missra
```

Please suggest me some workaround.

Comment: Add a space after Miss like Miss ',' '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` means end of line, and after `'^Miss'` you have space, not end of line. `'^Miss '` should work fine.  Also dots (literal `.`) should be shielded with `\\` because dot in regexp has special meaning - any character, and it seems you mean literally dot(`.`).

`^` - means the beginning of the line anchor, BTW first regex `Mr\\.` has no `^` anchor, fix it if it is not intentionally. If you want to replace these expressions not only in the beginning, remove all `^`

```
REGEXP_REPLACE('Miss Missra','Mr\\.|^Mr |^Ms\\. |^Ms |^Mrs\\. |^Mrs |^Dr\\. |^Dr |^Miss ',' ')
```